# Flutter/Firebase: Security concern for google-services.json

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

We are instructed to put `google-services.json` inside the Android and iOS folder. I wonder can other people read this file after they download the app from the app store, and cause security problems?

Comment: Once you publish your app, the data in that file effectively becomes public, and is not a security problem unless your security rules allow access that you don't want.